# Karma config to exclude nested directories

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am using karma for unit testing my angular 2 application. I have following directory structure -

```
└── src/
    ├── index.js
    ├── index.js.text
    ├── index.test.js
    ├── README.txt
    ├── startuptest.js
    ├── lib/
    |   ├── util.js
    |   ├── util.test.js
    |   └── filters/
    |       ├── kalman.js
    |       └── lowpass.js
    ├── test/
    |   ├── main.js
    |   └── lib/
    |       ├── filters.js
    |       └── util.js
    └── vendor/
        ├── jquery.js
        └── three/
            ├── three.js
            └── three.fps.js
```

I want to exclude all files under my

```
src/lib/!(filters)/**
```

from  coverage report. But I want to keep all the files from rest of the directory

I tried,

```
{src/**, src/lib/!(filters)/**}/!(*.spec!).js : coverage
```

But it's skipping everything.

How to do this?

Reference - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/508

Comment: How about `{src,src/!(lib/filters)/**}/*.js : coverage`? Or `{src,src/!(lib/filters)/**}/!(*test).js` to exclude also files with "test" suffix

Comment: That's not working. Unfortunately (

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

```
{src/*/!(lib/filters)/**}/!(*.spec!).js : coverage
```

If that doesn't work add a `coveragePreprocessor` to your karma config.

```
coveragePreprocessor: {
    exclude: [ "**/lib/filters/*.js" ]
}
```

Comment: I expect you might have another issue in your karma config then. Can you add the whole thing to the question.